# API controller with return type ActionResult does not accept OkObjectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create a C# API and instead of using controllers/minimal API I'm using the package [Ardalis.ApiEndpoints](https://github.com/ardalis/ApiEndpoints) ( which is based on controllers )

Based on a condition I don't want to respond with a 200, I tried the following example code

```
using Ardalis.ApiEndpoints;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProj;

public sealed class Handler : EndpointBaseAsync.WithoutRequest.WithActionResult<string>
{
    [HttpGet("foo")]
    public override Task<ActionResult<string>> HandleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (false)
        {
            return BadRequest("err");
        }

        return Ok("bar");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately my code is wrong, I get the error

> Cannot convert expression type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult' to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult>'

I tried to have a look at the sample code, e.g. https://github.com/ardalis/ApiEndpoints/blob/main/sample/SampleEndpointApp/Endpoints/Authors/Delete.cs

but I can't see the difference. Do you know what's wrong or missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create a C# API and instead of using controllers/minimal API
> I'm using the package.I get the error
>
> Cannot convert expression type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult' to return type
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult>'
>
> Do you know what's wrong or missing?

Well, based on the error message, description and shared code snippet it seems that your return type doesn't matched with your based controller class which has integrated as class library.

If you look at the details of `ardalis/ApiEndpoints` definition the method is expected to return a `Task<ActionResult>`, which is a promise of an action result that will be available in the future. But you are returnning `OkObjectResult` which is a concrete action result type, not a Task.

Because while you returning `BadRequest` it eventually returns `BadRequestObjectResult`  which is the type `OkObjectResult` and doesn't matched with your method signature, you can see below:

[image]

Another important point is that, `HandleAsync` method is designed to be asynchronous, meaning it can perform operations that might take time without blocking the thread. To handle this, it needs to return a Task, So along with Task you should use `async` as well.

In order to fix your issue, you can modify your code as following:

```
public sealed class Handler : EndpointBaseAsync.WithoutRequest.WithActionResult<string>
{
    [HttpGet("foo")]
    public override async Task<ActionResult<string>> HandleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (false) 
        {
            return BadRequest("err");
        }

        return Ok("bar");
    }
}
```

**Note:** Now back to your question, what's the wrong/mistake, that's the return type is wrong, The method's signature indicates that you must return a Task, not just an ActionResult and the Task should wrap with async.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your function to be like below, when you are returning a `Task` your function needs to have the async modifier. Check out the C# docs linked below to learn more about asynchronous programming.

```
public override async Task<ActionResult<string>> HandleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-return-types#tasktresult-return-type

Comment: _"You need to change"_ - no, OP does not =) Also `async` without `await` produces a warning (which will lead to compilation failure if "treat warnings as errors" is enabled).

Answer (score 1):

You defined the method to return `Task<ActionResult<string>>`, but the method is not marked as `async` (the `async` keyword is not present).

Either add the `async` keyword to the method (and consider make it doing async calls) -or- remove the `Task<>` around the return type.

Comment: Also `Task.FromResult<ActionResult<string>>`  is an option here. And based on `override` keyword removing `Task` highly likely is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `Task<IActionResult>` as return type?